# Regex to replace characters unless they're inside of a word?

Tags: python, regex

How do I replace a set of characters in a string unless they're part of a word? For example, if I have the text "ur the wurst person ur", I want to replace "ur" with "youre". So the final text would be "youre the wurst person youre". I don't want the "ur" inside of wurst to be changed because it's inside of a word. Is there a generic regex way to do this in python? I don't want to have to worry if "ur" has a space before or after, etc., only if it's part of another word. Thanks!

What I've tried so far is a simple

```
    result = re.sub("ur", "youare", text)
```

but this also replaces the "ur" inside of "wurst". If I use the word boundaries as in

```
    result = re.sub(r"\bur\b", "youare", text)
```

it will miss the last occurrence of "ur" in the string.

Comment: Word boundary `r'\bur\b'`

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: if you post the code you've tried, you'd get better answers

Comment: Do you have to solve this with regular expressions?

Comment: anubhava's solution works.

Answer (score 0):

## Without using regular expressions...

You could split the string at each space with `string.split()` and then, in a list comprehension, replace words `'ur'` with `'youre'`. This may look something like:

```
s = "ur the wurst person ur"

result = " ".join(['youre' if w == 'ur' else w for w in s.split()])
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`result = re.sub(r'\bur\b', r'youare', "ur the wurst person ur")`

from the python documentation:

> \b
>   Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of Unicode alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore Unicode character. Note that formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string. This means that r'\bfoo\b' matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'.